# How to add arguments in magento category URL

Tags: category, url-rewrite

I want to add my custom arguments on categroy url. For example I have 3 custom filters (links) on the category page (red, green, yellow) and the category page url is like:

`localhost/test/sale/accessories.html`

Now when a customer clicks on "red" the url should be like:

`localhost/test/sale/accessories.html?color=1`

Please help me on this.

I have modified two files already: `toolbar.phtml` and `list.phtml`

Comment: Try layer navigation

Answer (score 3):

This feature does exist in Magento and hence you don't want to do any extra code for do this.

Just make your category a layered category instead of a default category. That is the quick and easy solution for this. If you are confused with the terms ***default*** and ***layered***, then

- Default - A category which is not possible to filter down with any product attributes. For this, `isAnchor` property set to `NO`.
- Layered - A category which can be filtered by product attributes. For this `isAnchor` property set to `YES`.

By default, if you set your category as layered, and then make your color attribute as *visible in layered navigation* (which you can easily do through backend), then the feature that you are looking will be automatically available for you.

Or other wise, just make your color attribute links look like this.

```
www.domain.com/men/shirts.html?color=27
```

If you place such links for your color attribute options, then magento will automatically do a filter for you. ie links should somewhat look like this.

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <a href="www.domain.com/your-category-reference.html?color=27">Blue</a>
    </li>
     <li>
         <a href="www.domain.com/your-category-reference.html?color=29">Red</a>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="www.domain.com/your-category-reference.html?color=34">Green</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*Where color attribute values are assumed for demonstration*

Comment: Please check my edited question.

Comment: That simple edit changed the full meaning of your initial question. You should do that as a new question I think